# Spring Cloud Vault - Missing required header: X-Config-Token

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-vault

I was following the getting started guides for spring config server and vault when I run into a issue related to vault I am unable to resolve. The config server is however working fine with GIT but not with Vault. Below is the code and config I am using -

Here is the configserver code -

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
   public class SpringConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

And the corresponding `application.yml` -

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/weekly-drafts/config-repo-spring-cloud-configserver-vault
  profiles:
    active: default, native, git, vault
server:
  port: 8888
```

configserver `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.rockingengineering</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-config-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-config-server</name>
<description>Spring Config Server Application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Here is my configclient code

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class VaultApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(VaultApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and property loading controller. This code is loading properties from GIT but not vault.

```
@RefreshScope
@RestController
public class VaultController {

  @Value("${client.pseudo.property}")
  private String pseudoProperty;

  @Value("${client.pseudo.property.vault}")
  private String proeprtyFromVault;

  @GetMapping("/property")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getProperty() {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(pseudoProperty);
  }

  @GetMapping("/property/vault")
  public ResponseEntity<String> getPropertyFromVault() {
      return ResponseEntity.ok(proeprtyFromVault);
  }
}
```

Configclient  `bootstrap.yml` -

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configclient
  cloud:
    vault:
      token: f474964a-89bf-39e6-2e37-3d7de918f762
      uri: http://localhost:8888
    config:
      token: f474964a-89bf-39e6-2e37-3d7de918f762
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      headers:
        X-Vault-Token: f474964a-89bf-39e6-2e37-3d7de918f762
server:
  port: 8080
```

ConfigClient `pom.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.rockingengineering</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-vault</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-cloud-vault</name>
<description>Spring Cloud Vault Application</description>
<inceptionYear>2018</inceptionYear>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-cloud-vault-dependencies.version>1.0.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-vault-dependencies.version>

    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <finalName>spring-cloud-vault</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Response from Vault -

```
vault kv get -format=json secret/configclient
{
  "request_id": "1a8dba22-d120-f7b9-13a2-8f2107786c29",
  "lease_id": "",
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "client.pseudo.property.vault": "Property value loaded from Vault"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "created_time": "2018-10-11T12:36:24.165749Z",
      "deletion_time": "",
      "destroyed": false,
      "version": 2
    }
  },
  "warnings": null
}
```

I am able to use vault from CLI using the same token. The error I am getting is -

```
2018-10-11 18:07:49.946  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3fc2959f: startup date [Thu Oct 11 18:07:49 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-11 18:07:50.389  INFO 97999 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c21aa722] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-11 18:07:50.913  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2018-10-11 18:07:53.579  WARN 97999 --- [           main] o.s.v.a.LifecycleAwareSessionManager     : Cannot enhance VaultToken to a LoginToken: Token self-lookup failed: 500 {"timestamp":"2018-10-11T12:37:53.557+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No such label: token","path":"/v1/auth/token/lookup-self"}
2018-10-11 18:07:53.603  WARN 97999 --- [           main] LeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='secret/configclient', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Status 400 secret/configclient: {"timestamp":"2018-10-11T12:37:53.594+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Missing required header: X-Config-Token","path":"/v1/secret/configclient"}

2018-10-11 18:07:53.632  WARN 97999 --- [           main] LeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener : [RequestedSecret [path='secret/application', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Status 400 secret/application: {"timestamp":"2018-10-11T12:37:53.630+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Missing required header: X-Config-Token","path":"/v1/secret/application"}

org.springframework.vault.VaultException: Status 400 secret/application: {"timestamp":"2018-10-11T12:37:53.630+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Missing required header: X-Config-Token","path":"/v1/secret/application"}
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultResponses.buildException(VaultResponses.java:89) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultResponses.buildException(VaultResponses.java:81) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.lambda$doRead$1(VaultTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doWithSession(VaultTemplate.java:307) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doRead(VaultTemplate.java:317) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.read(VaultTemplate.java:212) ~[spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.doGetSecrets(SecretLeaseContainer.java:545) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.start(SecretLeaseContainer.java:357) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseContainer.addRequestedSecret(SecretLeaseContainer.java:316) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.loadProperties(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:147) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.vault.core.env.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.<init>(LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource.java:133) [spring-vault-core-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.createVaultPropertySource(LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.java:151) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.createVaultPropertySource(LeasingVaultPropertySourceLocator.java:88) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.doCreatePropertySources(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:170) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.createCompositePropertySource(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:145) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.vault.config.VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.locate(VaultPropertySourceLocatorSupport.java:116) [spring-cloud-vault-config-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:94) [spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:654) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:390) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.rockingengineering.vault.VaultApplication.main(VaultApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]

2018-10-11 18:07:53.633  INFO 97999 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='vault', propertySources=[LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource {name='secret/configclient'}, LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource {name='secret/application'}]}
2018-10-11 18:07:53.639  INFO 97999 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2018-10-11 18:07:56.496  INFO 97999 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=configclient, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
2018-10-11 18:07:56.496  INFO 97999 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='https://github.com/weekly-drafts/config-repo-spring-cloud-configserver-vault/configclient.yml'}]}
2018-10-11 18:07:56.502  INFO 97999 --- [           main] c.r.vault.VaultApplication               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-11 18:07:56.516  INFO 97999 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@60a2630a: startup date [Thu Oct 11 18:07:56 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3fc2959f
2018-10-11 18:07:57.909  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=e9255d82-de63-3800-b389-53a2229e780a
2018-10-11 18:07:58.032  INFO 97999 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c21aa722] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-10-11 18:07:58.564  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-10-11 18:07:58.589  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-10-11 18:07:58.589  INFO 97999 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
2018-10-11 18:07:58.593  INFO 97999 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/naveen/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-10-11 18:07:58.706  INFO 97999 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-10-11 18:07:58.706  INFO 97999 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2190 ms
2018-10-11 18:07:59.377  INFO 97999 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-10-11 18:07:59.965  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/property],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.rockingengineering.vault.controller.VaultController.getProperty()
2018-10-11 18:07:59.966  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/property/vault],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.rockingengineering.vault.controller.VaultController.getPropertyFromVault()
2018-10-11 18:07:59.969  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v2/api-docs],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || application/hal+json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-10-11 18:08:00.101  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-10-11 18:08:00.116  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-11 18:08:00.117  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2018-10-11 18:08:00.118  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto protected java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.links(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-10-11 18:08:00.266  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.397  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@60a2630a: startup date [Thu Oct 11 18:07:56 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3fc2959f
2018-10-11 18:08:00.443  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.443  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.798  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-10-11 18:08:00.811  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-11 18:08:00.812  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-11 18:08:00.815  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-10-11 18:08:00.821  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.831  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.842  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,context=60a2630a,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
2018-10-11 18:08:00.985  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-10-11 18:08:00.986  INFO 97999 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2018-10-11 18:08:01.004  INFO 97999 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2018-10-11 18:08:01.016  INFO 97999 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2018-10-11 18:08:01.099  WARN 97999 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.vaultController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'client.pseudo.property.vault' in value "${client.pseudo.property.vault}"
2018-10-11 18:08:01.101  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-10-11 18:08:01.102  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-10-11 18:08:01.107  INFO 97999 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-10-11 18:08:01.131  INFO 97999 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-10-11 18:08:01.138 ERROR 97999 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.vaultController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'client.pseudo.property.vault' in value "${client.pseudo.property.vault}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:378) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:390) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.rockingengineering.vault.VaultApplication.main(VaultApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'client.pseudo.property.vault' in value "${client.pseudo.property.vault}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

2018-10-11 18:08:01.139  INFO 97999 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3fc2959f: startup date [Thu Oct 11 18:07:49 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-11 18:08:01.141  INFO 97999 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService
```

Can anyone tell what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need to use `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config` for your config-client in this particular case. Basically your client doesn't know anything about Vault.  You just need to pass token (`spring.cloud.config.token`) and config-server will take care of getting properties from Vault using this token. `spring-cloud-starter-vault-config` is used in case when you want to get data directly from Vault (not through config-server). Your configuration (`bootstrap.yml`) should look like this:

   ```
   spring:
     application:
       name: configclient
     cloud:
       config:
         token: your_vault_token
         uri: http://localhost:8888
   ```
2. In config-server you need to support composite configuration from git and Vault. So you need to put 2 profiles: git and vault.
3. The tricky moment is that Vault has now 2 versions for KV Secrets Engine (https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/index.html) so make sure that you use same version in vault and config-server. Because based on documentation kv version 2 is enabled by default in dev mode:

> Additionally, when running a dev-mode server, the v2 kv secrets engine is enabled by default at the path secret/ (for non-dev servers, it is currently v1). It can be disabled, moved, or enabled multiple times at different paths. Each instance of the KV secrets engine is isolated and unique.

See: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html

Spring Cloud Config has support of both versions of Vault KV storage:

> Vault 0.10.0 introduced a versioned key-value backend (k/v backend version 2) that exposes a different API than earlier versions, it now requires a data/ between the mount path and the actual context path and wraps secrets in a data object. Setting kvVersion=2 will take this into account.
>   More: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#vault-backend

So based on all of this information, you configserver `application.yml` should look like this:

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring: 
  application:
    name: configserver
  profiles:
    active: git, vault
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          port: 8200
          host: 127.0.0.1
          kvVersion: 2  #may be 1 depends on Vault configuration
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/weekly-drafts/config-repo-spring-cloud-configserver-vault
```

Answer (score 1):

The right configuration is `spring.cloud.config.token`, you have the right config in the wrong file. Try adding it in `application.yml` instead, basically everything that comes before the **Spring Boot** Logo is configured through `bootstrap.yml` after the logo, Spring unloads `bootstrap.yml` and loads `application.yml` and then it tries to get the configuration from Spring Config Server.

What I usually do is to add is as an environment variable (`SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_TOKEN`), so no matter when it tries to reach the config, the value will be there.